# how to solve f(n) = f((3/4)n) + f(n^(1-b)) + c n^b

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

How can I solve this recurrence :

f(n) = f((3/4)n) + f(n^(1-b)) + c n^b

where b and c are constants and 0<b<1 and f(1)=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method

Comment: thanks David , f(n^(1-b)) confuse me @DavidEisenstat

Answer (score 1):

We cannot directly use Akra-Bazzi theorem as you have mentioned, because we cannot write
[image]
in the form of
[image]
such that
[image]
and
[image]
which is required for utilizing the theorem. However, we can find an upper bound by substituting
[image]
with
[image]
such that
[image]
is constant and less than
[image]
.
Now, we can use akra-bazzi theorem for
[image]
.
To continue, first we need to solve
[image]
in the following equation:

[image]

As we know in the integral part we have
[image]
,
if we choose
[image]
such that
[image]
,
the upper bound is
[image]
.

Hence, we can choose
[image]
which is less than
[image]
and a constant.